# How to get the 'status' column value in Windows explorer by PowerShell or java

Tags: windows, powershell

when we open a windows explorer, we will see multi-column, like this:

[image]

now, I want to get the status column(Circled in red) value by PowerShell or java, Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Status column? I haven't seen that before

Comment: Now you can see :) https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/status-column-in-file-explorer-in-windows-10/b3b99f8c-c43c-4c3a-a652-93dc5befc51b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include below function and modify as per your need in Powershell.

Below Powershell function can be used to get all details or properties of an item in file explorer.

```
function Get-FileMetaData {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Small function that gets metadata information from file providing similar output to what Explorer shows when viewing file
    .DESCRIPTION
    Small function that gets metadata information from file providing similar output to what Explorer shows when viewing file
    .PARAMETER File
    FileName or FileObject
    .EXAMPLE
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Env:USERPROFILE\Desktop -Force | Get-FileMetaData | Out-HtmlView -ScrollX -Filtering -AllProperties
    .EXAMPLE
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Env:USERPROFILE\Desktop -Force | Where-Object { $_.Attributes -like '*Hidden*' } | Get-FileMetaData | Out-HtmlView -ScrollX -Filtering -AllProperties
    .NOTES
    #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline)][Object] $File,
        [switch] $Signature
    )
    Process {
        foreach ($F in $File) {
            $MetaDataObject = [ordered] @{}
            if ($F -is [string]) {
                $FileInformation = Get-ItemProperty -Path $F
            } elseif ($F -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]) {
                #Write-Warning "Get-FileMetaData - Directories are not supported. Skipping $F."
                continue
            } elseif ($F -is [System.IO.FileInfo]) {
                $FileInformation = $F
            } else {
                Write-Warning "Get-FileMetaData - Only files are supported. Skipping $F."
                continue
            }
            $ShellApplication = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
            $ShellFolder = $ShellApplication.Namespace($FileInformation.Directory.FullName)
            $ShellFile = $ShellFolder.ParseName($FileInformation.Name)
            $MetaDataProperties = [ordered] @{}
            0..400 | ForEach-Object -Process {
                $DataValue = $ShellFolder.GetDetailsOf($null, $_)
                $PropertyValue = (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($DataValue.Trim()).Replace(' ', '')
                if ($PropertyValue -ne '') {
                    $MetaDataProperties["$_"] = $PropertyValue
                }
            }
            foreach ($Key in $MetaDataProperties.Keys) {
                $Property = $MetaDataProperties[$Key]
                $Value = $ShellFolder.GetDetailsOf($ShellFile, [int] $Key)
                if ($Property -in 'Attributes', 'Folder', 'Type', 'SpaceFree', 'TotalSize', 'SpaceUsed') {
                    continue
                }
                If (($null -ne $Value) -and ($Value -ne '')) {
                    $MetaDataObject["$Property"] = $Value
                }
            }
            if ($FileInformation.VersionInfo) {
                $SplitInfo = ([string] $FileInformation.VersionInfo).Split([char]13)
                foreach ($Item in $SplitInfo) {
                    $Property = $Item.Split(":").Trim()
                    if ($Property[0] -and $Property[1] -ne '') {
                        $MetaDataObject["$($Property[0])"] = $Property[1]
                    }
                }
            }
            $MetaDataObject["Attributes"] = $FileInformation.Attributes
            $MetaDataObject['IsReadOnly'] = $FileInformation.IsReadOnly
            $MetaDataObject['IsHidden'] = $FileInformation.Attributes -like '*Hidden*'
            $MetaDataObject['IsSystem'] = $FileInformation.Attributes -like '*System*'
            if ($Signature) {
                $DigitalSignature = Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath $FileInformation.Fullname
                $MetaDataObject['SignatureCertificateSubject'] = $DigitalSignature.SignerCertificate.Subject
                $MetaDataObject['SignatureCertificateIssuer'] = $DigitalSignature.SignerCertificate.Issuer
                $MetaDataObject['SignatureCertificateSerialNumber'] = $DigitalSignature.SignerCertificate.SerialNumber
                $MetaDataObject['SignatureCertificateNotBefore'] = $DigitalSignature.SignerCertificate.NotBefore
                $MetaDataObject['SignatureCertificateNotAfter'] = $DigitalSignature.SignerCertificate.NotAfter
                $MetaDataObject['SignatureCertificateThumbprint'] = $DigitalSignature.SignerCertificate.Thumbprint
                $MetaDataObject['SignatureStatus'] = $DigitalSignature.Status
                $MetaDataObject['IsOSBinary'] = $DigitalSignature.IsOSBinary
            }
            [PSCustomObject] $MetaDataObject
        }
    }
}
```

**Reference :**

**Follow Below Link for the complete tutorial.**

https://evotec.xyz/getting-file-metadata-with-powershell-similar-to-what-windows-explorer-provides/